# Write downloaded file location on json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-dl

I wrote this script :

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)


for obj in data:
    video_player_url = obj.get('video_url')
    ydl_opts = {}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([video_player_url])
    print(video_player_url)
    location = 'C:/Users/name/video/'obj.get('text')'.mp4'
    info = {"text": obj.get('text'), "video_location": 'location', "tags": obj.get('tags')}
    downloaded_file = open('downloaded_files','w+')
    json.dump(info, downloaded_file)
```

The download is fine, but I want to write the downloaded file location on a json file.
What I have here is giving me errors.

Writing the json file, what I am getting is:

```
{"text": "Title", "video_location": "C:/Users/name/video/video.mp4", "tags": ["", "tag", "", "tag2", "tag3"], "description": "great video"}{"text": "Title2", "video_location": "C:/Users/name/video/video2.mp4", "tags": ["", "tag", "", "tag2", "tag3"], "description": "great video2"}{"text": "Title3", "video_location": "C:/Users/name/video/video3.mp4", "tags": ["", "tag", "", "tag2", "tag3"], "description": "great video3"}
```

But what I want is:

```
[
{"text": "Title", "video_location": "C:/Users/name/video/video.mp4", "tags": ["", "tag", "", "tag2", "tag3"], "description": "great video"}
{"text": "Title2", "video_location": "C:/Users/name/video/video2.mp4", "tags": ["", "tag", "", "tag2", "tag3"], "description": "great video2"}
{"text": "Title3", "video_location": "C:/Users/name/video/video3.mp4", "tags": ["", "tag", "", "tag2", "tag3"], "description": "great video3"}
]
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Please add the error traceback. For sure, you have to change the `location` to `location = 'C:/Users/name/video/'+obj.get('text')+'.mp4'`.

Comment: `location = 'C:/Users/name/video/{}.mp4'.format(obj.get('text'))`

Comment: Yes, I fix it with 'C:/Users/name/video/'+obj.get('text')+'.mp4'. But while looping it keeps overwrite the first line.

Comment: What do you mean by "it keeps overwrite the first line"? One thing that caught my attention: In the `info = { ...}`, `location` should be a variable name and *not* a string.

Comment: I edit my question.

Comment: I can't see a difference there, except formatting (everything in [-]-brackets and newline char after each item). This should do the job, doesn't it? This is the syntax of json / json.dump, and that's how it is. If you want your own syntax, you have to add brackets and newline chars manually by adding e.g. `downloaded_file.write('\n')`. Btw, for good practice, you should either close your file object or use `with open(...) as downfile:`.

Answer (score 0):

It keeps overwriting because you are not storing your current dictionary anywhere you are just overriding the old one stored in `info`. Try using a `list` to store your `info` `dictionary`

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
data = json.load(f)

final_json_list = list()
for obj in data:
    video_player_url = obj.get('video_url')
    ydl_opts = {}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
         ydl.download([video_player_url])
    print(video_player_url)
    location = 'C:/Users/name/video/'obj.get('text')'.mp4'
    info = {"text": obj.get('text'), "video_location": 'location', "tags": obj.get('tags')}
    final_json_list.append(info)

downloaded_file = open('downloaded_files','w+')
json.dump(final_json_list, downloaded_file)
```